# What are the set of all functions from the set {0, 1} to {0, 1}

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble doing a homework problem, I do not understand what the question is asking. How do I write the set of all functions from the set {0,1} to {0,1} in an arrow diagram or sets of ordered pairs.

I'll leave the question for clarity:

Consider the set of all functions from the set {0, 1} to {0, 1}. Give a list of all possible such functions by writing them as sets of ordered pairs or as arrow diagrams. Which of these functions is one-to-one (injective)? Which of these functions is onto (surjective)?

Comment: Just do it.  Make a list of ordered pairs $f_i =\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3).....\}$ so that it obeys the rules of functions.  (The rules of function is that every $x_i$ is either $0$ or $1$ and you have *exactly* one of each.  ANd that each $y_i$ is either $0$ or $1$ no other rules.  Not every $0$ or $1$ has to be chosen and you can have as many [you can have it that *all* of them are one value] or as few of each as you like [you can have it that *none* of them are that value])  How many such lists of order pairs can you make.

Comment: Or just do it.  Take $0$ and $1$ and draw arrows $0\to y_1$ and $1\to y_2$  where the $y_i$ can be either $0$ or $1$.  How many different ways can you draw such arrow pictures. (Bear in mind you have have to have both mapped to... you can have them all map to one, or all map to another or have them map to any combinations).  How many such pictures can you draw?  (Hint: 4.  You can draw four of them)

Comment: As for arrow diagrams, you can basically see $\{0,1\}$ as just a set of two points. Draw two sets of two points, one on the left (or top), one on the right (or bottom, depends on if you prefer horizontal or vertical, doesn't matter). You can now draw a function of $\{0,1\}$ to $\{0,1\}$ as arrows that go from the left/top set to the right/bottom set, with one arrow per element of the first set that leads to only one element of the second.

Comment: A question like this assumes that in class you have already studied how to write a function as a set of ordered pairs and how to diagram a function with arrows. Did you study those topics? Was something unclear in the presentation of the methods? If you can identify where you got confused, that would make a more specific question we could help with.